# Create a new user and add new documents in Firebase database and add image in storage

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an app with flutter and I want to add information about the user account in the firebase database when I create it and add its profile image in the storage.
And I want to be sure that either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied like transaction!
Can you please tell me how doing it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to perform a transaction across multiple Firebase services, such as Authentication and the Realtime Database here.

You'll have to assume that the data *can* get corrupted and define a strategy how to deal with that both in the code that consumes the user data, and possibly in (server-side) code that performs a periodic cleanup.